# Posting files to a SharePoint 2019 list using SPFX

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am trying to upload files to a list item that I am creating using SPFX.  I have to do this on a SharePoint 2019 server and I am not using any libraries like React.  Below is the code I use to upload the files.  It works great with one exception.  I can't get the file to upload without metadata.  A simple text file with the word "Test" in it will be uploaded and look like this when you open it.

> *------WebKitFormBoundary7ZlPVABRPJrQ1qjn
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
> test
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7ZlPVABRPJrQ1qjn--*

Below is the code that I am using.  I think I need to add something to the headers or body, but not sure what to add.

```
private async uploadFile(file: File, itemId: number): Promise<void> {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file, file.name);
const response = await this.context.spHttpClient.post(
  `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyListName')/items(${itemId})/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='${file.name}')`,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
  {
    headers: [
      ["Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose"],
      ["content-type", "application/json;odata=nometadata"],
    ],
    body: formData,
  }
);

if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error("Error uploading file: " + file.name);
}
}
```

PLEASE HELP!

UPDATE:
I found this post:
[SPFX File upload to List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289291/spfx-file-upload-to-list)

This seems to work if I don't use FormData and just use "body: file" in the spHttpClient options.  FormData should've worked though.  Anyone know why?